# Calling state hook from outside its component

Tags: reactjs

When I run my current code it produces a button for each post in a local JSON file and if I click on the button it expands/contracts. I want to have a button that opens or closes all the posts but I'm unsure how to achieve this, my logic is that since `externalData` is an array of `Post` components, `handleClick` should simply be calling its own function but I get the error `element.setOpenStatus is not a function` when I press the Open All button.

```
function Post(props) {
  const [openStatus, setOpenStatus] = useState(true);

  if (openStatus) {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => setOpenStatus(false)}>
        <p>Title: {props.post.title}</p>
        <p>User: {props.post.user}</p>
        <p>Time: {props.post.time}</p>
        <p>Content: {props.post.content}</p>
        <hr />
      </button>
    );
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={() => setOpenStatus(true)}>
      <p>Title: {props.post.title}</p>
      <p>User: {props.post.user}</p>
      <p>Time: {props.post.time}</p>
      <hr />
    </button>
  );
}
```

```
class AllPosts extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      externalData: [],

    };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.renderPost = this.renderPost.bind(this);
  }

  renderPost(element) {
    return (
      <Post
        key={element.title}
        post={element}
      />
    )
  }

  checkIfExisting(post, key, value) {
    return post[key] === value;
  }

  // HERE things are going wrong
  handleClick() {
    this.state.externalData.forEach(element => {
      element.setOpenStatus({ openStatus: false });
    });
  }

  render() {
    this.props.data.forEach((element) => {
      if (!this.state.externalData.some(
        (post) => this.checkIfExisting(post, "key", element.title)
      )) {
        this.state.externalData.push(this.renderPost(element))
      }
    })

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>using local json file</h1>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Open All</button>
        <div>
          {this.state.externalData}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AllPosts;
```

Comment: You should really go through a react tutorial or two to get a handle on the basics of state management, passing callbacks, etc. It will answer all these questions and give you better examples then you'd probably come up with on your own. You can also extend their examples once you understand them further.

Comment: @ChadS. I am new to react but I did both react tutorials and am using the tic-tac-toe one as a base template for my code. I am clearly missing something but I am not sure how to proceed...

Comment: If you're following a tutorial that is having you use class based components I recommend using a different tutorial. This one uses the same application, but implements it using functional components https://matetiblog.wordpress.com/2020/02/10/title-react2-tic-tac-toe-game-functional-version-part-1/